# ASP.NET Core Web API using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I post a request to a table generated from joining two tables in Web API, and return only required columns?

This is the code for that:

```
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var clients = _db.Clients
                             .Include(cl => cl.Projects)
                             .ToList();

            return Ok(clients);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this code not working in some way?  It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: That's a lot of stuff to put in your title and I'm not sure what's relevant. Do you want to return only certain properties from your list `clients`?

Comment: From the name of your method, it would imply that you do not have a POST at all, but rather a GET.

Comment: Map your result to a class that has the desired shape

Comment: ... or `.Select()` it to an anonymous type before `.ToList()`.

Comment: Well i want to fetch required column on the basis of foreign key constraints and want to show some new columns in the table

Comment: i want to add new columns in clients table from projects table using linq join..but how can i post in that new table and update my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like that:

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        var clients = _db.Clients
                      .Include(cl => cl.Projects)
                      .Select(x => new {
                           ColumnName = x.PropertyName,
                           ColumnName2 = x.PropertyName2
                       })
                      .ToList();
        return Ok(clients);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

This way you create an anonymous object which you can use as you wish